# Laravel 5.6 RESRful Webervice update and delete

Tags: php, laravel, restful-architecture

I try to build a RESTful API in Laravel 5.6, now I also want do delete and update my database entrys with PUT and DELETE requests. If i use this code i get no error, I always get the messsage "Updated" or "Deleted" but de database never changes.

```
/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \App\Car  $car
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(Request $request, $number)
{
    $bus = Bus::findOrFail($number);
    $bus->update($request->all());

    return response()->json(["message" => "Updated"]);
}

/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  \App\Car  $car
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function destroy($number)
{
    Bus::find($number)->delete();

    return response()->json(["message" => "Deleted"]);
}
}
```

routes/api.php

```
 Route::get('bus', 'BusController@index');
 Route::post('bus', 'BusController@store');
 Route::put('bus/{number}', 'BusController@update');
 Route::delete('bus/{number}', 'BusController@delete');
```

Comment: Show your routes

Comment: i have added my routes/api.php file

Comment: you are using these routes from Laravel blade or external system???

Comment: from laravel blade

Comment: Did you put these lines in the beginning of **form** with `{{ csrf_field() }}`: `{{ method_field('PUT') }}` OR `{{ method_field('DELETE') }}` **???**

Comment: i try to send post requests from my postman on my laptop

Comment: If your route is put/delete than it wouldn't work with post

Comment: i also tried it with put and delte

Comment: Try setting **x-www-form-urlencoded** for body in postman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**LARAVEL BLADE**
If you are working with Laravel blade, just add `method_field` **(PUT/DELETE)** with `csrf_field` at the beginning of form, something like the following:

```
<form action="bus/<your_id_or_number>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

            {{ method_field('PUT') }}
            {{ csrf_field() }}

            ... rest of your code ...
</form>
```

---

**POSTMAN API**

**1.** If you are testing your API on postman, change the API method to **POST** and add a new field/parameter with key=**_method** and value=**PUT** as in the following image:

[image: _method field]

**2.** or use `x-www-form-urlencoded` in body part with method type as default **PUT/DELETE** like:

[image: x-www-form-urlencoded]

Comment: yes, change it to POST and add a paremeter with your request as mentioned above

Comment: I have added an example image for your ease